# R sparse logical matrix symbols

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

What do the `:` symbols denote in a sparse logical matrix in R?

I have shown some examples below:

```
> library(Matrix)
> m <- Matrix(c(0,0,2:0), 3,5)
> m
3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] . 1 . . 2
[2,] . . 2 . 1
[3,] 2 . 1 . .
> m > 1

3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "lgCMatrix"

[1,] . : . . |
[2,] . . | . :
[3,] | . : . .
> m > 2
3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "lgCMatrix"

[1,] . . . . .
[2,] . . . . .
[3,] . . . . .
```

Initially, I thought the `:` symbols denote non-absent False values in the sparse matrix `m` (with `|` as True), however, by looking at the `m > 2` example, this does not appear to be the case since all values are missing.

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on this either, but my initial thought is that you are correct in assuming that  `|` is true and `:` denotes non-absent false values, and the reason that you aren't seeing them in `m > 2` example is that since there aren't any data points that meet the criteria, no logic needs to be stored and thus the `|` and `:` symbols aren't necessary. Hopefully someone more familiar with the `Matrix` package can provide a more definitive explanation.

Comment: @scribbles I think you're correct:
`m <- Matrix(0, 3,5)`
`m[3,4] <- 1`
when querying `m > 1` it's all empty (`.`)
But add `m[2,3] <- 2` and you start to see `|` and `:`

Comment: if you're sufficiently satisfied with that info I'll switch it to an answer, otherwise I'll leave my comment as is.

Comment: I'd like to confirm this behaviour first. Going to comb through the Matrix source code from CRAN

Comment: Sounds good! I'm currently doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `:` represents non-missing `FALSE` values. One can play around some more, particularly using the `drop0` method, to see this is the case.  For example,

```
> m_gt1 <- m > 1
> m_gt1
3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "lgCMatrix"

[1,] . : . . |
[2,] . . | . :
[3,] | . : . .
> m_gt1@x
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> m_gt1_clean <- drop0(m_gt1)
> m_gt1_clean
3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "lgCMatrix"

[1,] . . . . |
[2,] . . | . .
[3,] | . . . .
> m_gt1_clean@x
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

That is, eliminating the non-missing `FALSE` values eliminates the `:` in the display.

As for the `m > 2` behavior: there is [a branch in the code for evaluating comparison operators](https://github.com/cran/Matrix/blob/1.2-15/R/Ops.R#L228) that checks to see if everything is `FALSE` and if so will drop the values (`@x` on the Matrix). Hence, you lose the non-missing evaluations and see the fully-sparse version.